# Table of contents, how to change name

Tags: templates, changes

I want to start with my first LaTeX project and I am using a couple of templates, but I've encountered a problem. The template seems to be using:

> \tableofcontents

For the table of contents, it looks good however I want to change the header from 'Contents' to something else, like 'Inhoudsopgave', but I can't seem to do that.

What is the solution?

Answer (score 1):

In some cases you can use the command `\renewcommand{\contentsname}{Inhoudsopgave}`.

In other cases (when you only want to change the language settings to Dutch) you should rather use a package for this cause (I recommend `babel`) like this.

```
\documentclass{book}

\usepackage[dutch]{babel}

\begin{document}

\tableofcontents

\end{document}
```